# Binding both value and text in select dropdown in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angular-ngmodel

I have this dropdown in my page

```
<select 
    ng-options="col.col_id as col.col_name for col in meta_data.x_cols"
    ng-model="obj.x">
</select>
```

Since the model is set to `obj.x`, I can access it using `$scope.obj.x` in any `$scope` function.

Naturally, it gives the `value` of the selected option. Is there any way by which I can get selected text as well? for e.g. bind `obj.x` to and `obj.x_text` to the text of selected option.

Comment: just drop the 'as' `ng-options="col.col_name for col in meta_data.x_cols"`. then your model will be the whole object. Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/LKeQz/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you bind col and not col.col_id:

```
<select 
    ng-options="col as col.col_name for col in meta_data.x_cols track by col.col_id"
    ng-model="obj.x">
</select>
```

you will be able to access both col_id and col_name from $scope.obj.x:

```
$scope.obj.x.col_id
$scope.obj.x.col_name
```

Comment: Hey, it solved that problem but created new problem. When I change the model, it doesn't update the view. I think because now its an object, equality would fail, since ({} != {}).

Comment: Can you share a plunkr illustrating the behaviour?

Comment: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x8rq2pda/3/. See how second select is not getting assigned value.

Comment: using angular 1.2 and above, you can use the track by, see http://jsfiddle.net/qomn86k3/

Comment: Thanks man, you're awesome. I wish I could re-accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ng-repeat on options tag..

for e.g

```
<select 
    ng-options="col.col_id as col.col_name for col in meta_data.x_cols"
    ng-model="obj.x">

    <option
      ng-repeat="col in meta_data.x_cols"
      value="{{col.id}}"
    >{{col.name}}</option>

</select>
```

Comment: I don't like this approach for large lists as the rendering is much slower in IE 11/Edge (I am sure other previous versions of IE too)